# How to perform all slow THREE.Texture computation at load instead of at runtime?

Tags: three.js

I'm setting a Scene containing many textured objects with high quality textures (resolution 1024x1024 and 2048x2048) and where each material has multiple maps (base color, normal, occlusion, roughness). To speed up the load and the rendering I'm already reusing the THREE.Texture objects when possible.

But just after load, when I rotate the viewpoint there is a clear slow down when new objects become visible. After all the textured objects have been rendered at least once the viewpoint rotation works smoothly as expected.
Note that if two objects share the same textures, only the first one will slow down the rendering when becoming visible.

Is there a way to compute everything at load in order to avoid this slow down when navigating into the scene?

I already tried to set `THREE.Object3D.frustumCulling` to true and call `THREE.WebGLRenderer.compile()` at load but I don't see any difference and the slow down remains.

Comment: You can load all the resources first and then start animation loop, using [`THREE.LoadingManager()`](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/loaders/managers/LoadingManager).

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! I will definitively look at this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found that the issue was simply a dummy typo..

the field is called `Objects3D.frustumCulled` and not `Objects3D.frustumCulling`.